# Can static variables be initialized in static methods?

Tags: c#

Can static variables be initialized in a method? Is the following code valid? Thank you!

```
internal static class Common
{

    internal static int TimeOut;
    internal static string Name;


    internal static void Initialize()
    {
        TimeOut = Config.Read("timeout");
        Name = Config.Read("Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Comment: In the amount of time it took you to post this, you could have put this code in your IDE and try to compile it 5 times over.

Comment: Side note, I've seen this done with some really strange exceptions happening. It can also make it hard to mock the type for unit testing, if it matters.

Comment: Being a big believer in dependency injection, this absolutely makes me cringe.  The only thing worse than a static class is a static class requiring you to call some kind of static initialize method before you use it!

Comment: @SteveDog: While I agree with the initialization being awful, I certainly wouldn't dismiss static classes as always being awful. How would you suggest implementing LINQ to Objects?

Comment: @JonSkeet What about LINQ to Objects are you saying requires staic classes?  I'm not very familiar with LINQ, so you've confused me.  I'm not saying that there is no use for a static class ever--especially when you have to work in someone else's code that's full of them.  But I would think long and hard if there was any other option before creating a new one.

Comment: @SteveDog: Well extension methods can only be declared in static classes, to start with... and LINQ to Objects is based on extension methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet you obviously have more expertise, but it would have been possible to use another trick to implement extensions. An `extension` modifier, and not have the `static` one. It can be a compiler trick in the same way. It would encourage people to create more types for everything. If they really want a class to be basically static, they can still have the private constructor. Just being the Devil's advocate, the current way is admittedly cleaner but arguably introduces the OP's question.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's just what I was going to say.  The only reason why extension methods require a static class is because that is the syntax of the language.  But extension methods are essentially instance-based methods--not static methods.  They just happen to require a static class to define them.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: What difference would that make? Fundamentally they'd still be static classes - ones where no instances were ever expected to be made, containing only static members.

Comment: @SteveDog: I was assuming it was something more fundamental to the static class that you objected to than the use of the keyword "static". If static classes were called "extension" classes, would that actually make them better in your view? How? What *real* difference would it make?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have no problem with the static keyword.  I have a problem with spaghetti code.  In the context of DI, as was my initial comment, most static classes have no seams.  In other words, there's no way for you to mock them or replace them with a different implementation.

Comment: @SteveDog: That's my point - changing the *syntax* of the language for extension methods wouldn't make change the seams. They'd still be non-polymorphic implementations. (Personally while I'm a big fan of DI in general, I also think the ability to mock *everything* is often overstated. I have no need to replace `List<T>` with a custom implementation, for example. I have no desire to replace LINQ to Objects. I want to mock *service-like* dependencies, which is a different kettle of fish.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It could have more requirements. Possibly that all public methods must be extensions. The question really is what's the goal. Microsoft's implementation seems to solve two problems. The first being extension methods, the second is a solution to all the people using `private myClass()` from .Net 1. This solution could lead to types which should be testable not being testable because they're written using `static`. While I agree with this implementation, I see the argument from the other side.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: Static classes do more than prevent construction. They *also* become self-documenting (you can't create an instance **because you're not meant to**) and they also allow the compiler to prevent you from declaring a variable of that type, etc. People will always be able to write untestable code - but there are plenty of times (IMO) when an implementation of a utility method will *never* want to be replaced for testing, and a static method is fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet I may have been using a bit of unnecessary hyperbole in my original post, and occasionally static classes have their place, but I stand by my assessment that the example code in this question screams spaghetti code.  If the class requires a Config object, it should request it.  It shouldn't lock the consumer into always providing the configuration in the same way.  It should also never just assume that the consumer will know that they need to call an Initialize method before it can be used.  What if Config is a static class and it uses some dependency that hasn't been initialized?

Comment: @JonSkeet I could argue that the GOTO statement isn't always a bad thing and doesn't always lead the spaghetti code, but that doesn't change the fact that it's very dangerous and best avoided by novices.

Comment: @SteveDog: I was never defending the code in the question. I was only questioning your hyperbole. There are many things worse than static classes, IMO. I'd argue that if a class requires a Config object, it should be provided to it rather than requesting it, but that's a different matter. (I'd also argue that instead of having one mammoth config class, each class should declare which *bits* of configuration it requires, and have those provided to it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Then we agree :)  I apologize for my hyperbole.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you're misunderstanding my goal. I'm not saying static classes are wrong, or there aren't places to use them. I'm saying there is an argument they the can contribute to misuse. Sure there are developers who will always misuse everything, I might be one of them, but the question is does the feature encourage that. In the same way that ASP.Net encouraged people to put all their code in to the codebehind, making it generally untestable and not reusable, the static class could be misused. I'm not arguing that in most cases it is not used appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can.  Your code is perfectly valid.

That being said, it's often better to *initialize* then in a static constructor, or inline, as it prevents them from being used and accessed prior to initialization.

In your case, this would require using a static constructor, as you're running code (`Config.Read`):

```
static Common()
{
    TimeOut = Config.Read("timeout");
    Name = Config.Read("Name");
}
```

I would also recommend using Properties instead of Fields for your static values, as this does provide some benefits, especially in terms of future-proofing your API.  This can be as simple as:

```
internal static int TimeOut { get; set; }
internal static string Name { get; set; }
```

In your case, since these appear to be read once at initialization, you could potentially also use:

```
internal static int TimeOut { get; private set; }
internal static string Name { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is yes.

If you truly want to initialize static variables (as in, set their value at runtime before the static class is used), use a static constructor:

```
internal static class Common
{
    internal static int TimeOut;
    internal static string Name;

    static Common()
    {
        TimeOut = Config.Read("timeout");
        Name = Config.Read("Name");
    }
}
```

Note, static constructors have no access modifier and must be parameter-less.

For further reading on [static constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.100).aspx), see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.100).aspx).